# Imageviews positioning over Imageviews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have three `ImageView`s positioned on top of one each other. But when the screen resolution or parent `ImageView` size changes, the child `ImageView`s position retain their old position. These old positions are wrong for the new parent `ImageView` size. How can I calculate the new positions? Or is there another way to solve this problem?

Every image on top of the dummy is an `ImageView` in this screenshot of my work:

[image: Every parent image on dummy an imageview in this screenshot.]

Answer (score 0):

I use absolute layout and it's work for me. Here is example code;

```
        <AbsoluteLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
            android:background="#eeeeee">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="@drawable/dummy2"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:layout_y="20dp"
                android:layout_x="30dp" />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="166dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/k_altkiy_v"
                android:layout_x="-2dp"
                android:layout_y="170dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/k_ustkiy_v"
                android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:layout_x="28dp"
                android:layout_y="66dp" />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="128dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/k_cek_v"
                android:layout_x="16dp"
                android:layout_y="50dp" />

        </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: I dont think so, that It is recommended to use `<AbsoluteLayout>` as it is already deprecated.@Emre Erol

Comment: @MaulikM.Dodia deprecated with what ? It is working fine right now. If it is deprecated then what is the solution ?

Comment: Actually I dont have any solution right now. If I will find, I'll get back to you. But **IMHO** it is not recommended to use any deprecated **METHODS** or any other older **TAGS** and **Google** have also given alternatives to them.@Emre Erol

Comment: @MaulikM.Dodia thanks a lot. Waiting your solution if you can find.